# How to make item fade in Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

**Hello!**

How do I make item fade in or fade out action? When you loose in my game it should be fading in things instead of just pop up. I code in Cocos2d 3.

Thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 0):

This will fade in an object in half a second

```
id action = [CCActionFadeIn actionWithDuration:0.5];
[ccNodeItem runAction:action];
```

and naturally this fades out an object in half a second:

```
id action = [CCActionFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.5];
[ccNodeItem runAction:action];
```